# If I can use ternary operator to react-native CSS?

Tags: css, react-native

I was trying to use the ternary operator to react-native CSS, but it doesn't work. If there is a way like this to make it work?

```
text: {
fontSize: 22,
textAlign: "center",
fontFamily: "Circular Std",
color: Text.name === "firstText" ? "#838383" : "#2EAA69"},
```

Comment: what do you mean by it didn't work? what was the resuting css?

Comment: You can. Depends on where you're using it, could you show more code?

Comment: You can if you use plain object instead of StyleSheet

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a ternary operator in the stylesheet of react-native component,
But there is an alternative which is called ["Styled component"](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can get the price of `Text.name`?

I wonder what Text is in your code.

In React Native, the ternary operator operates without any problems.

**example styles.js**

```js
import { Platform } from "react-native";
export default {
  container: {
    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === "ios" ? "rgb(126, 119, 255)" : "rgb(216, 216, 216)"
  },
```